# symfony5 How to order by the varcher column as number or natural sort

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a table with a column `price`, because of the largest possible number of price is far more then the `int8`, so I used `varchar(255)`, But it caused sorting problems.

At first, I used
`$qb->OrderBy("fin.price", 'ASC');`. And it didn't work surely.

Then, I used the way from other question
`$qb->OrderBy("fin.price::BIGINT", 'ASC');`. But got an error: `[Syntax Error] line 0, col 148: Error: Expected end of string, got ':'`.

And then, I tried
`$qb->OrderBy("INT(fin.price)", 'ASC');`. And got an error again:  `Expected known function, got 'INT'`.

At last. I tried to use `CREATE COLLATION numeric (provider = icu, locale = 'en@colNumeric=yes');` in database. But got `ERROR:  ICU is not supported in this build HINT:  You need to rebuild PostgreSQL using --with-icu.`.

I couldn't rebuild the database. So I can just reslove this problem by PHP. Is there any way to reslove this?

**DATABSE: postgres

ORM version: doctrine 2.9**

I'm not very proficient with this ORM yet.

Comment: Did you try `CAST(fin.price AS INT)`? Maybe add select then in order by.

Comment: Have you tried storing them as [NUMERIC/DECIMAL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html).

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the bigint directly?
When you create an entity the type is available.